# unknown option eventDrop erro

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I am not sure why I am getting an unknown option error. The events render appropriately. I can drag them but they revert back to their original date when I release them instead of the event dropping in the new date. I have Jquery-ui and the interaction plugin loaded.

```
import { Calendar } from '@fullcalendar/core';
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid';
import interactionPlugin, { Draggable } from '@fullcalendar/interaction';

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

  var calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
    plugins: [ dayGridPlugin,interactionPlugin],
    headerToolbar: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'dayGridDay,dayGridWeek,dayGridMonth'
      },
    editable: true,
    dayMaxEvents: true,
    events: '\_events.json',
    eventDrop: function(info) {
    alert(info.event.title + " was dropped on " + info.event.start.toISOString());

    if (!confirm("Are you sure about this change?")) {
      info.revert();
    }
  }

  });

  calendar.render();
 
});
```

The console error is

```
main.js?d610:7356 Unknown option 'eventDrop'
warnUnknownOptions @ main.js?d610:7356
CalendarDataManager._computeOptionsData @ main.js?d610:7143
eval @ main.js?d610:983
CalendarDataManager @ main.js?d610:6974
Calendar @ main.js?573d:53
eval @ index.js?b635:45
```

The error comes when the page loads before the user interacts with any of the events.

Comment: What's the full error message, and stack trace? When does it appear? Which line of code does it say causes the error? It seems odd. There's definitely an option called `eventDrop` in fullCalendar 5. Are there any other errors in your Console?

Comment: BTW you don't need `Draggable` unless you're intending to allow events to be dropped from outside the calendar, rather than just moved around within it.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about `Draggable`, I will take that out.

Comment: No problem. Thanks for the update. What is `main.js` in this context? Is it from the fullcalendar core library? I will assume so unless you mention otherwise. This seems very odd. Are you certain that the interaction plugin loaded successfully? Are there any errors or warnings in either the Console or the Network tool which suggest that it might not have done?

Comment: Yes, main.js is from fullcalendar. I don't see anything else that tells me if FullCalendar loaded incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had this exact same issue. The calendar itself worked fine, but `unknown option eventDrop` was in my console when the calendar loaded.

In my case it turned out to be because my interactionPlugin component had been installed after the initial calendar component and I had a mismatch in versions between all the pieces. Once I updated all components to use the same version (5.10.1 at the time of this writing) everything worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I had to move my

```
import interactionPlugin from'@/fullcalendar/interaction'
```

above

```
import FullCalendar, { CalendarOptions, EventApi, DateSelectArg, EventClickArg } from '@fullcalendar/vue3'
```

The package versions didn't matter in my case.

Comment: In my case it was  `dateClick` not `eventDrop`